# Wondering how to number outliers when using qqnorm?

Tags: r

In R, I'm wondering how to get `qqnorm` to number its outliers (I've circled these in red, below).

Here is an example. I do a linear regression:

```
lm1 <- lm (y ~ x)
```

I then plot the model:

```
plot(lm1)
```

This produces a very nice QQ plot. You can see that it numbers the outliers (I've circled this in red).

[image]

However, if I do my own qqnorm, the outliers are not numbered. How can I number these outliers, just like in the previous graph?

```
qqnorm(y)
qqline(y)
```

[image]

Comment: What about `plot(lm1, which = 2)`?

Comment: Roman Luštrik I didn't know this was possible. If you add it as an answer, I'll definitely upvote it.

Comment: You already did. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @Roman Luštrik Thank you ever so much, very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learn to look at the code:

```
 plot.lm
 # snipping the rather long output top and bottom and showing hte relevant section
 if (show[2L]) {
    ylim <- range(rs, na.rm = TRUE)
    ylim[2L] <- ylim[2L] + diff(ylim) * 0.075
    dev.hold()
    qq <- qqnorm(rs, main = main, ylab = ylab23, ylim = ylim, 
        ...)
    if (qqline) 
        qqline(rs, lty = 3, col = "gray50")
    if (one.fig) 
        title(sub = sub.caption, ...)
    mtext(getCaption(2), 3, 0.25, cex = cex.caption)
    if (id.n > 0) 
        text.id(qq$x[show.rs], qq$y[show.rs], show.rs)
    dev.flush()
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. How did you look at the code - did you download the source of the package and examine that?

Comment: It's way easier than that. I just typed the function name at the console. Code appears. It can be more involved than that and in some instances you might have needed to type getAnywhere(plot.lm). There is a very useful article  http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2006-4.pdf ; (page 43) about getting code by Uwe Ligges. Google it with a strategy of: Ligges accessing sources

Answer (score 6):

Another very simple way is the following:

```
QQ_y=qqnorm(y)
identify(QQ_y)
```

The code will pause here. Hover over your plot, click on the assumed outliers or other points of interest, then control click or escape to continue code.

```
qqline(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on answer by @DWin, if I add the line:

```
text(qq$x[44]-0.2, qq$y[44], 44)
```

Then it adds a number the plot:

[image]

To do this properly, you would have to write code to:

- Sort the x,y values values returned by qqnorm into order (making sure you keep each pair of x,y values together).
- Label the first three and the last three with their index number.

As I am using a QQ plot for exploratory data analysis only, the following answer by Roman Luštrik is a lot easier:

```
plot(lm1, which = 2)
```